# How can I customize the entity template IntelliJ uses?

Tags: hibernate, templates, intellij-idea

I'm trying to find the file template that IntelliJ uses to generate entities from a database and am having trouble hunting it down.  I've been into Settings -> File Templates and can't seem to find it anywhere.  Is this something that can be customized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these classes are generated using IntelliJ's [PSI tree](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+Architectural+Overview#IntelliJIDEAArchitecturalOverview-PsiElements) API, i.e. by some kind of AST which is then converted to Java code. So there's no template you can modify, and since the Java EE plugin is not open source, you have no other option to generate different classes...